# Broken Words Cryptic #3

Tags: word, wordplay

This game can be also played here: https://www.brainzilla.com/word-games/broken-words/cryptic/3/

Use the following chunks to create words related to a specific theme. The theme name itself is also hidden within those words.

<kbd>DLE</kbd> - <kbd>HSH</kbd> - <kbd>SAI</kbd> - <kbd>LIE</kbd> - <kbd>DOG</kbd> - <kbd>VER</kbd> - <kbd>DAL</kbd> - <kbd>EDS</kbd> - <kbd>COL</kbd> - <kbd>ING</kbd> - <kbd>RIE</kbd> - <kbd>DAC</kbd> - <kbd>ERN</kbd> - <kbd>DEN</kbd> - <kbd>GLE</kbd> - <kbd>MAT</kbd> - <kbd>PEK</kbd> - <kbd>ATD</kbd> - <kbd>ESE</kbd> - <kbd>ANE</kbd> - <kbd>BEA</kbd> - <kbd>ARD</kbd> - <kbd>RET</kbd> - <kbd>IAN</kbd> - <kbd>BRE</kbd> - <kbd>GRE</kbd> - <kbd>NTB</kbd> - <kbd>GOL</kbd> - <kbd>UND</kbd> - <kbd>POO</kbd>

Theme: ?

- ?
- ?
- ?
- ?
- ?
- ?
- ?
- ?
- ?

All the answers have a multiple of three letters.

Comment: "All the answers have a multiple of three letters." ...is that a trick statement?

Comment: @BruceWayne not at all. Why do you ask? Maybe it's not properly written since English is my second language.

Comment: Oh, just because (unless I'm missing something) all the chunks have three letters, so any answer would have a multiple of three letters :P

Comment: @BruceWayne you're not missing anything. Of course, I don't know why I thought this would be necessary here. That's what I get for cutting my morning caffeine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are ...

> POO+DLE  (Poodle)
>  GRE+ATD+ANE  (Great Dane)
>  GOL+DEN+RET+RIE+VER  (Golden Retriever)
>  SAI+NTB+ERN+ARD  (Saint Bernard)
>  DAL+MAT+IAN  (Dalmatian)
>  COL+LIE  (Collie)
>  BEA+GLE  (Beagle)
>  PEK+ING+ESE  (Pekingese)
>  DAC+HSH+UND  (Dachshund)

which are all

> DOG+BRE+EDS (**Dog Breeds**)

Comment: Of course *you* solved it :-)

Answer (score 3):

The theme is

> DOG BREEDS

And the answers are

> DALMATION 
> BEAGLE
> GREAT DANE
> POODLE
> DACHSHUND
> GOLDEN RETRIEVER
> COLLIE
> SAINT BERNARD (@Rubio)
> PEKINGESE (@Rubio)